# createImagebitmap on main thread?

Tags: javascript, angular, bitmap, pixi.js

I have problem with lags while replacing textures so I decided to use createImagebitmap(it did not help). As far as I know, it should work on separated threads, not on the main one. While using dev-tools performance sections it is displayed as it is working on the main thread. Is that correct? (I'm using angular+pixi.js on Chrome)

[image: main-thread]

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a single threaded language. This means it has one call stack and one memory heap. As expected, it executes code in order and must finish executing a piece code before moving onto the next. Please see: https://dev.to/steelvoltage/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd

HTML5 and CSS3 are multithreaded, but javascript is not.

Comment: I understand but using createImagebitmap should not be done in separated worker when it comes to decoding as described here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/createimagebitmap-in-chrome-50 ?

Comment: @majkel Are you creating a separate WebWorker for this? Unless you are using a browser that supports WebWorkers and are specifically creating WebWorkers to handle the call it will not use a background thread: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: I understand. I thought using createImagebitmap guarantees handling it on a background thread. Do you have any suggestions what I can do to get of rid of lags? Should I create manually workers (if they are available)?

Comment: Most modern browsers support WebWorkers, so this would be a handy way of supporting it. Depending on your application you may be able to pre-load your images and keep them cached (to prevent re-rendering). Effectively you load as much as you can from the start and then hide what you don't need until you use it. Another possible option, depending on your app, would be to use CSS as much as possible for updating/rendering. Since CSS is multithreaded it allows seamless visual updates w/o interfering w/ the core javascript.